# How to deploy custom webparts, html and javascript files to office 365

Tags: 2013, powershell, office-365, csom

I have created a custom web part file (dwp file)

It is basically a content editor web part which I exported after pointing it to a HTML file

Now I want to deploy the following files in folders as mentioned below

```
 dwp files -> _catalogs/wp
 HTML files-> style library/HTML
 JS files  -> style library/JS
```

Currently I am manually navigating to these folders and uploading them

How can I do this via `Powershell`, `CSOM` or any other tool from my system?

Answer (score 1):

I use a console application built using CSOM to upload files, you can use it to upload files to SharePoint library as below. Here, I am uploading html files to a Style Library folder called HTML. It iterates through a folder in local machine and uploads all files to HTML folder of Style library.

You can modify it to upload to JS folder as well as change the URLs to upload to master page gallery.

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteCollectionurl");
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Repository\HTML");
foreach (string filePath in files)
{   
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    string fileUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", "/Style Library/HTML/", fileName);    
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(context, fileUrl, fs, true);
    }
}
```